# Javascript Object Behaviour

Tags: javascript, object

I'm pretty new to JS objects. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this result?

> hey arnold

While my desired output is:

> hey amy

Here's the code

```
function greet (person) {       
    if (person == { name: 'amy' }) {
        console.log('hey amy')
    } else {
        console.log('hey arnold')
    }
}
greet({ name: 'amy' })
```

Comment: If only object comparison was that easy :)

Comment: you are basically comparing an object here. Obviously your if condition is not satisfied that's why else is getting executed

Comment: Well, really you should do `console.log('hey ' + person.name)`… ;)

Comment: Object matching only awaible for refferer point. In your case they have difference pointers. You can use JSON stringify maybe.